# How to print each line containing regex pattern and sort them alphabetically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, sorting

I have a test_list.txt file containing lines of file names. Each file name contains the date when they were created. Here's how it looks like:

test_list.txt:

```
UTF_06012018_SAMPLE_Control.xlsx
UTF_06022018_SAMPLE_Control.xlsx
UTF_06092018_SAMPLE_Control.xlsx
UTF_06022018_SAMPLE_Control.xlsx
UTF_06082018_SAMPLE_Control.xlsx  
UTF_06032018_SAMPLE_Demand.xlsx               
UTF_06092018_SAMPLE_Demand.xlsx  
UTF_06122018_SAMPLE_Demand.xlsx
UTF_06032018_SAMPLE_Control.xlsx
UTF_06022018_SAMPLE_Demand.xlsx
```

The date in the file name is in the format mmddyyyy. Also, there are files which were created on the same date. What I'm trying to do is to print the line that matches the regex expression for the dates and sort them alphabetically by date.

Here's my code so far:

```
path = Dir.glob('/path/to/my/file/*.txt').first
regex = /(\d{1,2}\d{1,2}\d{4})/

samplefile = File.open(path)
string = File.read(samplefile)

string.scan(regex).each do|x|
    sorted = x.sort_by { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i }
 puts sorted
end
```

However, what my code does is it only prints the dates, not the entire line. To add to that, it doesn't even sort them alphabetically. How to tweak it and make it do as I intend to?

Comment: @Allan the file that I open and read is a .txt file, the content of that file is simply a list of names of .xlsx files :)

Comment: Looks like `string.split("\n").sort.join("\n")` already does it, doesn't it?

Comment: If you have more complex strings, try `string.scan(/^([^_]*_(\d++)(.*))/).sort_by { |m,n,z| [n.to_i,z] }.collect{ |m,n,z| m}.join("\n")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that did it :) If you can post it as an official answer I can mark it as accepted for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
string.scan(/^([^_]*_(\d++)(.*))/).sort_by { |m,n,z| [n.to_i,z] }.collect{ |m,n,z| m}.join("\n")
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/jOT8uV).

The regex will extract all lines into a three element array with the following values: whole line, the date string, and the string after the date. Then, `.sort_by { |m,n,z| [n.to_i,z] }` will sort by the date string first, and then by the substring after the date. The `.collect{ |m,n,z| m}` will only keep the first value of the array elements and `.join("\n")` will re-build the resulting string.

Note that instead of `[n.to_i,z]`, you might want to parse the date string first, then use `[Date.strptime(n,"%d%m%Y"),z]` (add `require 'date'`).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `([^_]*_(\d++)(.*))`  - Group 1 (`m`): the whole line meeting the following patterns:

  - `[^_]*` - zero or more chars other than `_`
  - `_`  - an underscore
  - `(\d++)` - Group 2 (`n`):  1+ digits, a possessive match
  - `(.*)` - Group 3 (`z`): the rest of the line.